# Why is vcpkg recommended as a git submodule?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

Currently the [README.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/2022.09.27#quick-start-windows) for vcpkg says

"First, download and bootstrap vcpkg itself; it can be installed anywhere, but generally we recommend using vcpkg as a submodule for CMake projects, and installing it globally for Visual Studio projects."

Why is the recommendation submodules for CMake? But global for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is the recommendation submodules for CMake?

The README is kind of out of date. The current advice for CMake uses would be to use `FetchContent` since it is less of a hassle compared to a git submodules.

> But global for Visual Studio?

The is also kind of dated. The reason for it is that vcpkg + VS required integration with a vcpkg instance (`vcpkg integrate install`) but today there is also (`vcpkg integrate project`) which could be used. Still having per project setup is kind of a manual setup while having it globally is less manual since vcpkg is directly integrated into VS/MSBuild without having extra setup steps in VS.

Furthermore, at the time the advice was written, binary caching wasn't yet implemented so per project integration would probably have meant a rebuild for every project referencing a different vcpkg instance.

In the end it the suggestion comes down to ease of use. You don't have to do it the suggested way.

Comment: Just a note on this. @Alexander Neumann's suggestion was accurate for an entire 12 days before the vcpkg team removed the section in the readme regarding `FetchContent`. I have a personal aversion to committing large, mostly-unrelated submodules to my projects, so I experimented with trying to use `FetchContent` in conjunction with vcpkg. In the end I kept `FetchContent` and dropped vcpkg. `FetchContent` is entirely sufficient for my needs, and I would encourage CMake users considering vcpkg to investigate if `FetchContent` alone works for their use case.

Comment: And the reason it was removed is: Deleting the build folder will also remove the checked out vcpkg version and thus vcpkg needs to be checked out again by `FetchContent` (which might take some time). The solution to that is simply to tell `FetchContent` to move vcpkg out of the normal build folder to somewhere else. But personally I don't think it matters which approach is used to get vcpkg. There are benefits and drawbacks for either approach.